# Is it alright to put a UPS right next to a PC?

Tags: ups, interference

Due to lack of space I'm considering placing a UPS right next to a PC. The UPS is a Niky 1100(VA), a somewhat powerful, yet low-quality machine. Should I be worried about any magnetic field this thing is producing that could effect the PC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPS systems are a essentially a battery charger when you get right down to it. EMI only really comes into play at higher voltages. The 230 Volts that this system operates at generates so little EMI that I don't even think it would mess with wireless signals, let alone the computer itself.

What you should be concerned about is cable management, easy access, and battery failures. When you place the UPS, make sure you can easily get to the device if you have to service it. Batteries are only good for a certain number of years before needing to be replaced. Plan for this eventuality so when (not if) it needs to be replaced, it is a painless process. One that you don't have to go digging past a rat nest of cables. Other then that, put it out of the way so it's not being tripped over and move onto the next issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for the nice tip about planning for future battery replacements

Answer (score 4):

Not really, especially if your PC's case is metallic and closed.

If it affects anything in that way it would be analog connections. You *might* hear a difference in your speakers (unlikely since 60 Hz isn't audible) and it might affect your display if you are using an analog connection to your monitor.

It will not erase your disks. The days when a (normal) stray magnet could erase disks are long past.

Comment: It affect my analog monitor.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is always recommended to keep them at least 30 Centimetres away in most of the manuals I see and I typically keep them about a meter away when setting up for clients, however when I go back to the same sites, they usually have moved them next to the machines and I have never seen any problems arise from it.

Answer (score 0):

I have kept UPSs near my mcahine before without any problems.  I think you'll be okay.  I would expect the UPS designers to anticipate UPSs being right next to the machine and have determined that the elctromagnetic interference is small enough.